# Access DB Transaction on insert or updating

Tags: c#, transactions, ms-access-2007

I am going to implement the database access layer of the Window application using C#. The database (.accdb) is located to the project files. When it comes to two notebooks (clients) connecting to one access database through switches, it throws DBConcurrency Exception Error. My target is to check the timestamp of the sql executed first and then run the sql .
Would you please provide me some guidelines to achieve this ?

The below is my code

```
        protected void btnTransaction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string custID = txtID.Text;
        string CompName = txtCompany.Text;
        string contact = txtContact.Text;
        string city = txtCity.Text;


        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomersDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        OleDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, City, Country) VALUES(@CustomerID, @CompanyName, @ContactName, @City, @Country)";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", custID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", CompName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", contact);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = @ContactName2 WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID2";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID2", custIDUpdate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName2", contactUpdate);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            adapter.Fill(table);
            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            transaction.Commit();
            lblMessage.Text = "Transaction successfully completed";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            lblMessage.Text = "Transaction is not completed";
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice a couple of things:

1. Your INSERT CommandText has a `@Country` parameter specified, but you don't add a corresponding parameter to the `.Parameters` collection.
2. You try to re-use the `command` object for your UPDATE by changing the CommandText and adding more parameters, but you don't get rid of the previous parameters from your INSERT so presumably they're still in place, which could definitely confuse the UPDATE command.
3. You specify the UPDATE parameters in the wrong order. ACE.OLEDB **ignores** parameter names, so the parameters must be added to the `.Parameters` collection in the *exact* order that they appear in the CommandText.

I'm also confused as to:

- why you don't commit the transaction *before* trying to bind the GridView, and
- why you need a transaction at all, since the INSERT and the UPDATE appear to be unrelated.